# recommended screen for use in the sun

Tags: screen

im thinking of making a raspberry pi system for use with electronic targets and need help in selection of the screen

the system will be used outdoors so i need a screen that can be seen outdoors, i was looking at https://www.waveshare.com/10.1inch-HDMI-LCD-B-with-case.htm does anyone have any experiences with that screen and is it easy to see outdoors.
 thanks

Comment: Shopping recommendations are explicitly off-topic per the site's FAQ, however, have you considered a low tech approach shielding the monitor from the sun.

Answer (score 1):

Those are regular LCD screens, not ultra-bright / AMOLED used on high-end cell phones. Such screens are practically unreadable under direct sunlight.

As far as I can tell, these particular screens are also not designed to be used outdoors, as they lack any protection from dust and water.